# Rails - Keep a variable as you go through .each

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 3.2 view that is creating a list.  If the `costestimate.costcat.position` is equal to 1 (there is only one of these in the list), I want to save a variable to be used in the rest of the list.

```
      <% @costproject.costestimates.each do |costestimate| %>
        <% if costestimate.costcat.position = 1 %>
            <% $constructioncost = costestimate.amount %>
        <% end %>
        <% if costestimate.costcat.typical != nil %>
           <% costtypical = costestimate.costcat.typical * $constructioncost %>
        <% end %>
        <td><%= costtypical %></td>
        <td><%= costestimate.notes %></td>
```

But, after each cycle, the $constructioncost becomes zero.  I thought $ would make it a global variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because you use assignment operator instead of comparison `if costestimate.costcat.position = 1` should be `if costestimate.costcat.position == 1`

I'd advise against both using global variables and having all that logic in the view. In your case if you have that single multiplier for every `costestimate` in `costproject` it might make sense to save it inside of `costproject`. Calculating `costtypical` for each `costestimate` could be done inside of `costestimate` class, or a helper, or a service object, or somewhere else, depending on how your app is structured. Just not in the view.

At the very least get your var outside the loop and without global var:

```
<% constructioncost = @costproject.costestimates.find{|c| c.costcat.position == 1}.amount %>
<% @costproject.costestimates.each do |costestimate| %>
    <% if costestimate.costcat.typical != nil %>
       <% costtypical = costestimate.costcat.typical * constructioncost %>
    <% end %>
    <td><%= costtypical %></td>
    <td><%= costestimate.notes %></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be an error in your code causing weird results:

```
<% if costestimate.costcat.position = 1 %>
```

should be

```
<%  if costestimate.costcat.position == 1 %>
```